# How to divide imputed data with 'survSplit' function and finally pool the analysis results using 'pool' function in MICE package

Tags: r, r-mice

When I do cox regression using R, I found the proporitonal hazard assumption is violated. So I decided to divide the data into different time intervals using the 'survSplit' function and calculate the HR for each time interval.

For example:

## 1) divide data into different time intervals

```
`D1 <- survSplit(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data= data1, cut=c(40, 60),
episode= "tgroup", id="id")`
```

## 2) to get HR for each time interval

```
`coxph(Surv(tstart, time, status) ~ age + class:strata(tgroup), data=D1)`
```

Now I want to do the same for multiply-imputed datasets (n=5).

## step 1 data imputation

`imp <- mice(data1, seed = 12345, n=5,print = FALSE)`

## step 2 reanalysis

```
fit <- with(imp, coxph(Surv(tstart, time, status) ~ age + class:strata(tgroup))
```

## step 3 pool the results

```
`summary(pool(fit))`
```

My question is how I can post process the imputed data to divide each imputed dataset into different time intervals using 'survSplit' between step 1 and step 2. After post-processing, I can continue to do step 2 and step3.

Although I can extract each imputed dataset and then divide it using 'survSplit', I am not able to continue step2 and step 3 using the MICE package. Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the best approach is to use `{}` inside the `with()` command, which will allow you to place multiple statements inside. Here's a demonstration, based on the example in the `survSplit()` documentation.

```r
library(survival)
library(mice)
set.seed(123)

# use the veteran dataset with some values made missing
veteran2 <- veteran
veteran2[which(rbinom(nrow(veteran2),1,0.1) == 1),
         "karno"] <- NA
# make imputations
imps <- mice(veteran2, printFlag = FALSE)
# fit the models, with survSplit used inside each call
mods <- with(imps, 
             {
               dat <- data.frame(mget(ls()))
               dat_split <- survSplit(Surv(time, status) ~ ., 
                                      data = dat,
                                      cut = c(60, 120), 
                                      episode = "timegroup")
               coxph(Surv(tstart, time, status) ~ karno*strata(timegroup), 
                     data = dat_split)
             })
pooled <- pool(mods)
summary(pooled)
#>                                 term    estimate   std.error statistic
#> 1                              karno -0.04986785 0.007715564 -6.463279
#> 2 karno:strata(timegroup)timegroup=2  0.03645985 0.015247181  2.391252
#> 3 karno:strata(timegroup)timegroup=3  0.04104428 0.013389159  3.065486
#>          df      p.value
#> 1  70.51041 1.141572e-08
#> 2  94.68223 1.876833e-02
#> 3 108.83144 2.740870e-03

c(t0_60 = pooled$pooled$estimate[1],
  t60_120 = sum(pooled$pooled$estimate[c(1,2)]),
  t_120 = sum(pooled$pooled$estimate[c(1,3)]))
#>        t0_60      t60_120        t_120 
#> -0.049867847 -0.013407999 -0.008823565
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I know the meaning of the statement  "dat <- data.frame(mget(ls()))"

Comment: Also, do you know how to get the 95% CI for the three estimates: t0_60, t60_120, and t_120? Thank you.

Comment: @fliang `mice` doesn't automatically create a dataframe inside the function. So we need to get the list of names inside the function, get those values, and then combine them into a dataframe. That's what `data.frame(mget(ls()))` does.

Comment: To get CIs for those estimates you'd need to do something a bit different. First you'd need to estimate each of those values inside the mice function, rather than estimate the model parameters. Then you might need to find an appropriate transformation of them to be approximately normally distributed. Then you can pool them using standard pooling techniques. Finally if you made a transformation you'd need to transform them back to the usual scale. I'd recommend asking about it on Cross Validated if you have trouble.